# Hash Table sequence always get inserted

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

I have a problem related to the hash tables.

Let's consider an hash table of dimension `2^n` in a open linear schema.

1. `h(k,i) = (k^n + 2*i)mod(2^n)`.  Show that the sequence
   `{1,2,...2^n}` always can be inserted into the hash table.

I tried to identify a pattern in the way the numbers get inserted into the table and then apply an induction to see if I can prove the question.Any problem which our teacher gave us seems to be like this one, and I can't figure out a way of doing these kind of problems.

Comment: Did you leave the words "without collision" out of the problem statement?

Comment: @stark the collision occurs but they are solved through linear probing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `h(k,i) = (k^n + 2*i)mod(2^n)`. Show that the sequence `{1,2,...2^n}` always can be inserted into the hash table.

Two observations about the hash function:

- `k^n`, for `n >= 1`, will be odd when `k` is odd, and even when `k` is even
- `2*i` will probe every second bucket (wrapping around from last to first)

So, as you hash `{1,2,...2^n}` we know you'll alternate between finding an unused odd-indexed bucket, and an even-indexed bucket.

Just to emphasise the point, the `k^n` bit restricts the odd keys to odd-indexed buckets and the even keys to even-indexed buckets, while `2*i` ensures all such buckets are considered until a free one's found.  It's necessary that exactly half the keys will be odd and half even for the table to become full without `h(k,i)` failing to find an unused bucket as `i` is incremented.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of terminology problems here.

1. You hash table does not have [dimensions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dimension.html) (actually it has, but it is one dimension, and not 2^n), but it has number of slots/buckets.
2. Most probably the question you asked is not the question your book/teacher wants you to solve. You tell:

> Show that the sequence {1,2,...2^n} always can be inserted into the
>   hash table

and the problem is that in your case any natural number can be inserted in your hash table. This is obvious, because your hash function maps any number to a natural number in a region from [0 to 2^n) and because your hash function has 2^n slots, any number will fit in your hash.

---

So clarify what your teacher wants, explain find out what k and i is in your hash function and ask another, better prepared question.

Comment: But if the hash function is not a good funnction and then during the insert operation there is a loop and an empty slot is never found ?

Comment: @Drago and where in the question do you tell that this if forbidden? In any normal hash it is expected to have more than 1 values for a key?

Comment: Basically I need to show that even if a collision is occurred,based on the given formula an empty slot is always found.

Comment: Here is the link https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/open-addr.html describing the open addresing with linear probing.